# Need help creating IsValidPassword for PBKDF2 in C#

Tags: c#, pbkdf2

Having the hardest time trying to create a PBKDF2 valid password checker. The PBKDF2 code comes from a SharpHash project; https://github.com/ron4fun/SharpHash. The Class is: SharpHash/SharpHash.Tests/KDF/PBKDF2_HMACTests.cs

The example shows how to implement it but does not have any examples on how to verify the hash afterwards. I managed to tried several different "IsValidPassword" is one of the methods, but none of them seem to work. Each and every one of them the result is false no matter what values I add to the PBKDF2 or IsValidPassword methods. I also tried changing to a hex and also base64 but got the same results; it failed.

I even replaced Rfc2898DeriveBytes.

Does anyone have any experience with PBKDF2 password verification. This would be application based, not website based. IDE environment Visual Studios 2019 - C#.

Thank you.

```
    public void TestOne()
    {
        IPBKDF2_HMAC PBKDF2 = HashFactory.KDF.PBKDF2_HMAC.CreatePBKDF2_HMAC(hash, Password, Salt, 100000);
        byte[] Key = PBKDF2.GetBytes(64);
        PBKDF2.Clear();

        string ActualString = Converters.ConvertBytesToHexString(Key, false);

        Assert.AreEqual(ExpectedString, ActualString);
    }



public bool IsValidPassword(string password, string hashPass)
    {
        bool result = false;

        // Extract the bytes
        byte[] hashBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hashPass);
        // Get the salt
        byte[] salt = new byte[20]; // Doesn't matter what values and here; same issue… False
        Array.Copy(hashBytes, 0, salt, 0, 20);// Doesn't matter what values and here; same issue… False
        // Compute the hash on the password the user entered
        var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, 100000);
        byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(64);
        // compare the results
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) // If I go to 64 I get an error
        {
            if (hashBytes[i + 20] != hash[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }


// Replaced Rfc2898DeriveBytes
        public bool IsValidPassword(string password, string hashPass)
    {
        bool result = false;
        IHash hash1 = HashFactory.Crypto.CreateSHA1();
        // Extract the bytes
        byte[] hashBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hashPass);
        byte[] Password = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
        // Get the salt
        byte[] salt = new byte[20]; // Doesn't matter what values and here; same issue… False
        Array.Copy(hashBytes, 0, salt, 0, 20); // Doesn't matter what values and here; same issue… False
        // Compute the hash on the password the user entered
        var pbkdf2 = HashFactory.KDF.PBKDF2_HMAC.CreatePBKDF2_HMAC(hash1, Password, salt, 100000); // Replaced Rfc2898DeriveBytes
        byte[] Key = pbkdf2.GetBytes(64);
        pbkdf2.Clear();
        string test = Converters.ConvertBytesToHexString(Key, false); // Taking a peek
        string test2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(hashBytes); // Taking a peek
        // compare the results
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            if (hashBytes[i + 20] != Key[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I suppose this will help someone else down the road apiece. I had to do some serious searching and banging my head up against the wall because this was my first attempt at PBKDF2 to come up with a functional verification method that isn't included with the SharpHash project. Just so that anyone reading this would understand what my problem was. The code generated the password with no issues whatsoever. However, there was no function in the code project that actually verified the password using the salt, generated password and iteration.

The code provided is the simple version because I have also added overloads to the methods that I don't need to post. This method has default settings whereas one of the overloads allows for complete customization of the hash algorithm, salt and iteration. Each of these I had tested and they worked as expected.

Hope this helps someone. :-)

```
private static Int32 Salt256bit { get; } = 256 / 8; // 256 bits = 32 Bytes
        public static string GetHashPBKDF2Password(string password)
    {
        // Notes:
        // Create a 32-byte secure salt and the same size of the key. This 32-byte produces 256 bits key output.
        // Add the same 32-byte size to the pbkdf2.GetBytes.
        // KDF.PBKDF2_HMAC.CreatePBKDF2_HMAC hashes these values using the crypto SHA presented.
        // Double the hashBytes bytes then add the salt and pbkdf2.GetBytes value.
        // Copy each of the 32-bytes to the hashBytes bytes from the hashed salt and hashed value.
        //
        byte[] Password = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
        string hashPass = string.Empty;

        // Create the salt value with a cryptographic PRNG
        byte[] salt;
        new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(salt = new byte[ByteSize]); // 32 Bytes = 256 bits.

        // Create the KDF.PBKDF2_HMAC.CreatePBKDF2_HMAC and get the hash value using the SHA presented.
        // I know SHA1 is not that secured at all anymore. Just using it to test with. :-)
        IHash sha = HashFactory.Crypto.CreateSHA1();
        IPBKDF2_HMAC pbkdf2 = HashFactory.KDF.PBKDF2_HMAC.CreatePBKDF2_HMAC(sha, Password, salt, Pbkdf2Iterations);
        byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(ByteSize); // 32 Bytes = 256 bits.

        // Double the size of the byte array to include the "pbkdf2.GetBytes" and salt.
        Int32 g = hash.Length + salt.Length;
        byte[] hashBytes = new byte[g];

        // Combine the salt and password bytes.
        Array.Copy(salt, 0, hashBytes, 0, ByteSize);
        Array.Copy(hash, 0, hashBytes, ByteSize, ByteSize);

        // Turn the combined salt+hash into a string for storage
        hashPass = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);

        return hashPass;
    }

    public static bool ValidatePBKDF2Password(string password, string hashPass)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] Password = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
            bool result = true;

            // Extract the bytes
            byte[] hashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hashPass);
            // Get the salt
            byte[] salt = new byte[32];
            Array.Copy(hashBytes, 0, salt, 0, 32);
            // Compute the hash on the password that user entered.
            // I know SHA1 is not that secured at all anymore. Just using it to test with. :-)
            IHash hash1 = HashFactory.Crypto.CreateSHA1();
            IPBKDF2_HMAC pbkdf2 = HashFactory.KDF.PBKDF2_HMAC.CreatePBKDF2_HMAC(hash1, Password, salt, Pbkdf2Iterations);
            byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(32);
            // compare the results
            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            {
                if (hashBytes[i + 32] != hash[i])
                {
                    result = false;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    How to use:     string GeneratedHash = PBKDF2Helper.GetHashPBKDF2Password("password");
    Results: hv6t8N4rrVSKYFm80cCoVUEiUk2o11xLBc6lJb5kBXKTcwcKwl9dZwSdce01X0bi8BBhJY/QGGnNVAcR7ZhSvQ==

    Verify Paword:  Boolean tester = PBKDF2Helper.ValidatePBKDF2Password("password", GeneratedHash);
                    txtVerificationResults.Text = tester.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

taking a quick look at this, the issue you are encountering is simply a misrepresentation of the data contents involved.
`password` is a `base256` based data while `hashPass` is a `base16` based data.
You have to use the appropriate conversion routine when converting `hashPass` to `byte[]`.
To do that, simply use [this](https://github.com/ron4fun/SharpHash/blob/master/SharpHash/Utils/Converters.cs#L294) method found in the Converters class too.

```
byte[] hashBytes = Converters.ConvertHexStringToBytes(hashPass);
```

Do note that I assumed that your password is in `base256` (since you didn't specify this in the question) so you can leave it as it is.
The only change you need to make is the one I described above.